# Apache Log grok pattern

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logging, filebeat, grok

Can anybody please help with the grok pattern for below example of logs?

> **85.85.85.85 webmail.company.com "CN=First Last/O=Company/C=CZ" [14/Dec/2020:05:58:18 +0100] "GET /mail/User.nsf/iNotes/Proxy/?OpenDocument&Form=s_ReadViewEntries&PresetFields=DBQuotaInfo;1,FolderName;($Inbox),UnreadCountInfo;1,SearchSort;DateD,s_UsingHttps;1,noPI;1&TZType=UTC&Start=1&Count=23&resortdescending=6 HTTP/1.1" 200 2054 "https://webmail.company.com/mail/User.nsf/iNotes/Proxy/?OpenDocument&Form=l_ScriptFrame&l=en&gz&CR&MX&TSF=20170318T181650,92Z&TSX=20180206T185427,18Z&EFF=%2FiNotes%2FForms9_x&charset=UTF-8&charset=UTF-8&KIC&ua=safari&pt" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" 125 INOTES_LOGIN_ID=First%20Last; Shimmer=SI_TLM:20210209T072811%2C40Z&ST_Counter:3&LAO:mail&SAB:1&CS_TLM:20210209T072831%2C15Z&V_TLM:20210210T080147%2C82Z&DMS:5&ui:X&MOTLM:20210129T113159%2C00Z&DBQS:1503571%2C%207168000%2C%206963200%2C%200%2C%201503571&SPRKL:1&KOSCZ:GTB&FISD:1; INOTES_LOGIN_ID=First%20Last; DWAShared=0; DWAMode=0; INOTES_LOGIN_ID=First%20Last; DWAShared=0; DWAMode=0; LtpaToken2=FpoGJJz33bYLI+CtWy6OlIgoTJouNGEiduvxvQbcN8HRI7K6LThCsb1Dl8CzN72Zi05RGOUmQRMiOQcTk1norKHi6SbkEGI6GlXzjSIweBRSc8c+XPyAwA44PKPbu3WzrPfR0+uoC0sgTPvochvQ/VfPL/sSaqUFoRswRwyI+UeaOwTs/DvKiWLCpiKrVkFk3SmDjrxPBHb/WiL5nDkpp8Dsjjxnlo4vpx7BdOoVNai1jybvHkW28KXxkb21o8SSpmU7ZFdHyZFjDWCYuuCVOx7asV/q4a3lWdxlPfWdPcUguHML+xDmsrMPm6fTUSKeKIKdQEPr6VDmitBi7Z5URIlkRrUyslkTcc28y6fQir3Y20Hc9TmOvwaBlG/ehnpv; LtpaToken=0x4JJ4oWKojdqoz08Ng+MRUkkJq2vYGLGN9lp8HL8FxbD+xnivE7qzCzf92Q6x5OAPOBFRNgxd3Qg225zLwnJFWO0lGeIweH8VDgyWOMImNe6E9z9HBnQAN43vQ2uwtpv3X5E5DN0oLIPKLxAkqsHUDJqJ0SE6NZ6UnfLoR82JyjZVC/s6QEov5DNdpAY/o2Gxh0vWmE+wuQGuCh4mVCIP9KU/dbX4F0Ld9JEExzIpkdzKELibU2Akov0Krv0eWADSV++m/5ECLpaf6N6/VzkZEkt5XoOoL6OD/6ni4zojvo3O+X9Bn7Mdk2MnsQ1AccIohj5eN8Oi81QbD0a9b7jw==; ShimmerS=ET:20210210T114045%2c00Z&R:0&AT:M" "D:/Lotus/Domino/Data/mail/User.nsf"**

What I would need is **Client IP** (85.85.85.85), **VirtualHostname** (webmail / webmail.company.com) , **User** (part after CN=, First Last), **Time** (14/Dec/2020:05:58:18), **URL** (GET /mail/User.nsf/iNotes/Proxy/?OpenDocument&Form=s_ReadViewEntries&PresetFields=DBQuotaInfo;1,FolderName; ... ) and the **Device Info** ( "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" )

I know it should start with below, however I can't get anyhow the User name to proceed with [%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}] and possible next would be "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request} and not sure how to get the Device info.
Any help would be appreciated!

> %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{WORD:VirtualHost} ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{IPORHOST:destination.domain} "CN=%{DATA:username}" [%{HTTPDATE:apache.access.time}] "(?:%{WORD:http.request.method} %{DATA:url.original} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http.version}|-)?" %{NUMBER:http.response.status_code:long} (?:%{NUMBER:http.response.body.bytes:long}|-) ("%{DATA:http.request.referrer}") ("%{DATA:user_agent.original}")

Answer (score 0):

Since you have customized your log format, you have to build your own grok to match the log. You can use https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to debug the pattern you're going to use and you can copy some patterns from https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns